# anchor tag nesting alternative

Tags: jquery, html

**Description :**

Simply putting it I have a notification in which it says that

foo uploaded a picture on bars profile e.g.
in html like this

```
<a href = "somepage.php">

<div>

<a href = ""> foo </a> uploaded a picture on <a> bars </a> profile

</div>

</a>
```

What I have right now is when user clicks foo it takes user to foo's profile and same for the bar 
What I want is when user click the div any where but the foo and bar it takes the user to somepage ...

**What I Found :**

I read here that nesting of a tags is not allowed and browsers do restrict this so a tag eventualy ends when a new one starts even if its the child a tag ... so one way or another we cant do a tag nesting ... Then how am I supposed to achieve this like facebook offers us the exact same options to go to the profiles of persons or go to the notification it self

**What have i tried:**

I have tried to give id's to foo and bar and onclick go to a link via jquery but this is not the way to achieve it ...

Is there any other way to do it ??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the markup in the question is the *real* markup you have (or close to it), simply use `a` elements in succession, instead of trying to nest them:

```
<div>
<a href=""> foo </a><a href="somepage.php"> uploaded a picture on </a>
<a href="..."> bars </a><a href="somepage.php"> profile</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

@Rks Rock Exactally what i understood you want to send the control to "somepage.php" when a user clicks on

```
<div>

<a href = ""> foo </a> uploaded a picture on <a> bars </a> profile

</div>
```

Is it right ??

It this is there you can achieve this functionality from jquery click event.

Have you tried jquery .click event.

Comment: thats what i already told that it can be done with jquery ... I was asking is there another way to do it .. if